# What does this sentence mean? 我初次看見他是沒念中學以前

Tags: meaning

from DeFrancis' *Beginning Chinese Reader* p. 184 – Lesson 19, Exercise 5, Item 5

Answer (score 1):

You can understand this sentence in this sentence pattern: **“某事发生在某事以前”** which means **"sth. happed before sth."**

The first thing is **“我初次看见他”**, which means **"the first time to meet sb."**

The second thing is **“没念中学”**, which means **"haven't participated in middle school courses"**, maybe in elementary school.

For example, I going to middle school at 12, so I may meet him the first time at 11. Or I am going to middle school in Sep. 2012, so I may meet him the first time in Apr.2012.

---

*I am Chinese and if you are confused with my English grammar, you can read this Chinese bellow:*

这句话的可以用这个句式理解：**“某事发生在某事以前”**

第一件事是 “**我初次看见他**”，即 **第一次遇到/认识某人**。

第二件事是 “**没念中学**”，即 **还没有参加中学课程**，可能是在上小学。

比如原文中的“我”在12岁时上中学，那么“我”有可能是在 11 岁的时第一次遇到/认识“他”，或者“我”在 2012 年 9 月上中学，“我”也有可能是在 2012 年 4 月的时第一次遇到/认识“他”